# How to implement TintableBackgroundView for Android API < 21?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I would like to Tint my ToggleButton, which doesn't available in Tintable View support library. Currently I am using appcompat support library v23.1.0

To make ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList() works, the View needs to implement [TintableBackgroundView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.view.View,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)).

However, there is almost 0 example of how to do this. I looked into the source code of AppCompatButton (which implements TintableBackgroundView), it used of a private class AppCompatBackgroundHelper, which is not accessible outside of the support library.

Any idea?

Comment: Tint at runtime or as part of your theme?

Comment: Tint it at runtime. Since below API21, it is not yet supported to Tint at theme yet.

Comment: Well, AppCompat tints via your theme pre API 21 - that why `AppCompatButton` exists. Is tinting via theme still not what you're looking for?

Comment: But I am looking for AppCompat for ToggleButton. It is not exist, so I am looking to implement it myself.